# Dynamic Serving of Website

Tags: responsive-design, http-headers, responsiveness

For a responsive Website I prefer Dynamic Serving, But i don't know how it work the link is here 
https://developers.google.com/webmasters/mobile-sites/mobile-seo/dynamic-serving

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So i fount the solution use
**GET /page-1 HTTP/1.1
Host: www.example.com
(...rest of HTTP request headers...)
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Type: text/html
Vary: User-Agent
Content-Length: 5710
(... rest of HTTP response headers...)**